# Why is the fonts-iosevka package not included in Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, fonts

I'd like to install the Iosevka font on Ubuntu 22.04.

The instructions on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka) say 'install one of the fonts-iosevka packages'. When I do `apt-search fonts-`, lots of packages for other fonts are listed, but fonts-iosevka is not. I have *main*, *universe*, *restricted*, and *multiverse* repos enabled.

Why is this package not included?

Comment: It's open source, meaning if the license under which it's created is compatible, it only needs someone to package (*with skills & privileges etc*) & upload it into repositories. If it existed in Debian, most packages will auto-flow through into Ubuntu as well, but again someone needs to actually package & upload there. Getting people to step up & help do this work has always been difficult.

Comment: If anybody wants to contribute to the community by adding this package to Debian and Ubuntu, the place to begin learning how is http://mentors.debian.net

Answer (score 3):

The string "install one of the fonts-iosevka packages" is a link to a third party repository. You can download it from there if you like.

It's not in the Debian/Ubuntu archives because nobody has uploaded it yet. Related Debian bug:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=973995